# Does the Swift compiler automatically vectorize loops as an optimization?

Tags: swift, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, auto-vectorization

I’m taking a class on parallel/distributed computing and was wondering if the Swift compiler performs any auto vectorization to optimize loops. I understand that LLVM performs a lot (all?) of the optimizations. I found this page that details some of its auto vectorization optimizations, which states that it is on by default: (https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html#the-loop-vectorizer)

I was wondering if this is still true for Swift, since it’s built on top of LLVM. Also would these optimizations occur at the SIL or IR level? I’m new to compilers so please correct me if my understanding is not correct. Thanks

Comment: Yes it does perform vectorization as it is based on LLVM. The optimizations happen at the level of IR.

Comment: @ConsistentProgrammer It's worth noting that, at least when Swift was first introduced, it did not seem to vectorize loops. Not sure if that has changed: https://www.geekbench.com/blog/2014/12/swift-performance/